# How to post data to another website?

Tags: c#, http-post

i have the URL to which i need to redirect the user and post the data

http://newurl.com/?postdata=here_goes_the_data_you_like_to_post

and this website  receives my parameter;

sample parameter to be posted is

parameter='FIELD=4&VALUE=000000375368;FIELD=41&VALUE=60800001;FIELD=42&VALUE=201403818000001;FIELD=215&VALUE=4F3112EC-E92E-42A9-96C2-C8D9FDF87326;FIELD=223&VALUE=127.0.0.1;FIELD=226&VALUE=LEDESMA,%20SARAH%20LOPEZ;FIELD=290&VALUE=A@MAIL.COM;FIELD=299&VALUE=SALE;FIELD=810&VALUE=393823;FIELD=811&VALUE=04072014';

now what is the code for posting this? using c#

i need to post in the partner site..i need to send them the payment data since the site is a payment site.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough... Do you mean in client side or post is within your code block in server-side? Please explain the situation more

Comment: you can use that method: http://www.stickler.de/information/code-snippets/httpwebrequest-post-data.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx <- what you need.

Comment: i need to post in the partner site..i need to send them the payment data since the site is a payment site

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user to another url, for example: http://newurl.com, and the data can be posted like: http://newurl.com/?postdata=here_goes_the_data_you_like_to_post

From the new url you need script which will resolve the url and get the data after '?postdata='.

Comment: i need to post securely..i think this method is unsecured